# Deleting files command line/git

Tags: git, github

I'm taking an online course and the video had me download git and create a repository for Github.

I created a folder (named coursera-test) and somehow added 2 files/directories accidentally when I was trying to perform the "cd .." function. They are named "." and the other ".." (refer to attached images). When I sent my folder to Github it uploaded a file named ".." which is wrong according to the video.

I need to delete the local version completely. I have already deleted it from Github. When I try to delete it using `rmdir coursera-test`, I get the error saying "the directory is not empty". When I enter into the file there are the two mistake directories. When I try to delete the files using `del`, nothing happens. When I try to use `rmdir` it says "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." I also tried running as admin and coursera-test isn't showing up! I have no idea what to do from here. I have tried researching and nothing!

command line text:

```
Directory of C:\Users\lopez\coursera-test

03/13/2021 11:39 PM <DIR> . 
03/13/2021 11:39 PM <DIR> .. 
0 File(s) 0 bytes 2 Dir(s) 868,329,132,032 bytes free

C:\Users\lopez\coursera-test>cd..

C:\Users\lopez>rmdri coursera-test 
'rmdri' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\lopez>rmdir coursera-test 
The directory is not empty.

C:\Users\lopez>dir 
Volume in drive C is OS Volume Serial Number is 6A1B-E830

Directory of C:\Users\lopez

03/13/2021 09:47 PM <DIR> .
03/13/2021 09:47 PM <DIR> .. 
03/09/2021 12:23 PM <DIR> .config 
11/23/2019 08:08 AM <DIR> .cricut-design-space 
09/01/2019 09:09 PM <DIR> .dotnet 
03/09/2021 01:07 PM 61 .gitconfig 
11/21/2019 07:34 PM <DIR> .vscode 
11/05/2020 09:50 PM <DIR> 3D Objects 
11/05/2020 09:50 PM <DIR> Contacts 
03/13/2021 11:39 PM <DIR> coursera-test 
03/10/2021 10:50 PM <DIR> Creative Cloud Files 
12/09/2020 04:36 PM <DIR> Documents 
03/10/2021 06:34 PM <DIR> Downloads 
11/05/2020 09:50 PM <DIR> Favorites 
11/05/2020 09:50 PM <DIR> Links 
11/05/2020 09:50 PM <DIR> Music 
03/13/2021 09:02 PM <DIR> OneDrive 
10/29/2019 02:33 AM <DIR> Roaming 
11/05/2020 09:50 PM <DIR> Saved Games 
11/05/2020 09:50 PM <DIR> Searches 
11/05/2020 09:50 PM <DIR> Videos 
1 File(s) 61 bytes 20 Dir(s) 868,329,132,032 bytes free

C:\Users\lopez>cd coursera-test

C:\Users\lopez\coursera-test>dir Volume in drive C is OS Volume Serial Number is 6A1B-E830

Directory of C:\Users\lopez\coursera-test

03/13/2021 11:39 PM <DIR> . 
03/13/2021 11:39 PM <DIR> .. 
0 File(s) 0 bytes 2 Dir(s) 868,329,132,032 bytes free

C:\Users\lopez\coursera-test>del . 
C:\Users\lopez\coursera-test*, Are you sure (Y/N)? y

C:\Users\lopez\coursera-test>dir 
Volume in drive C is OS Volume Serial Number is 6A1B-E830

Directory of C:\Users\lopez\coursera-test

03/13/2021 11:39 PM <DIR> . 
03/13/2021 11:39 PM <DIR> .. 
0 File(s) 0 bytes 2 Dir(s) 868,328,312,832 bytes free

C:\Users\lopez\coursera-test>rmdir . 
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

C:\Users\lopez\coursera-test>
```

[image]

Comment: `.` and `..` are entries that exist in all directories that have a parent (the root directory will only have `.`), they are NOT errors.

Comment: thank you for clarifying. but because i did not know this i believe i messed something up because now it is not pushing to github. can you please help me with this?